# Synchronize application with firebase post push notification when application is suspended

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am in the beginning stages of developing a react native mobile application. I wanted to get insights on the following on a conceptual level relating to the below.

Say the application goes into the suspended state (as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)) at which point there is no application code being executed. Subsequently, the server sends a push notification based on some changes to the data. It seems that (at least on IOS) there is a way to use push notifications to initiate a download in the background. My questions are:

1. Is there a way to initiate this download in react native post a push notification when application is suspended?
2. Is there a way to synchronize the Firebase data with the application post such a push notification while the application is running in background if (1) above is possible?

Any hints on these will be of great help. Thank you.